# Visualization workflow of large Pandas datasets

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-multiprocessing

I am handling datasets of several GB, which I process in parallel with the *multiprocessing* library.
It takes a lot of time, but it make sense.

Once I have the resultant dataset, I need to plot it.
In this particular case, through *matplotlib*, I generate my stacked bar chart with:

```
plot = df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
fig = plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig('plot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

At this point, for large datasets, is simply unmanageable. This method is performed sequentially, so it does not care how many cores do you have.
The generated plot is saved in a *pdf*, which in turn, is also really heavy, and slow to open.

Is there any alternative workflow to generate lighter plots?

So far, I've tried with dropping alternate rows from the original dataset (this process may be repeated several times, until reaching a more handy dataset). This is done with:

```
df = df.iloc[::2]
```

Let's say that it sort of work. However, I'd like to know if there are other approaches for this.
How do you face this type of large dimension visualization?

Comment: Usually, you don't. Meaning you don't plot more bars than you can clearly see on a page. One would hence probably review if this kind of plot is really suitable for the kind of data you want to show.

Comment: maybe this can guide you http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Large_Data.html